# Knowledge management and e-learning software

Tags: wiki, help-desk, knowledge-organization

We are looking for a software or multiple but integrated software to support helpdesk, sales and other people in our company.

We'd like the following features but we could cope with just a subset of it:

- web-based, wiki-style editing of documentation/pages
- version history support
- suggested edit queue (like on Stack Exchange)
- email notification on changed content with inline diff (on subscribe/watch in Confluence)
- exam module:

  - users can write questions and potential answers
  - documentation should be in the same place as related questions/answers (we want to avoid the case of deprecated questions due to two-place editing)
- questions/pages could be categorized onto topics
- creating exams with random questions from the same or group of topics
- users could take these exams
- track of user's taken exams
- daily practice quiz sessions with 5-10 questions ([Leitner system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leitner_system) should be great)
- settable read/write permissions for users/groups (for pages)
- multi-language support for documentation and questions

  - should be easy to keep multiple languages in sync, so it should be easy to figure out those pages where not all language has been upgraded/changed
- read confirmation: admins could create pages which must be read by other users

  - users have to confirm that they read the page
  - listable confirmed page versions
  - listable users who has not read the required documents/pages
  - lists for users for their unread documents

Environment:

- preferably should run on Linux servers
- Atlassian Confluence integration could be great (storing documentation in Confluence, for example)